# Net functions behave slightly different for IPv4 from IPv6. Why?

Tags: google-bigquery, ipv6

I'm using BigQuery to truncate IPv4 & IP46 IP addresses. By that I mean I want to drop the part that might be used to identify a real person.

Here's some demo code:

```sql
select *,
        NET.IP_TO_STRING(NET.IP_TRUNC(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(v.IPv4Address), 24)),
        NET.IP_TO_STRING(NET.IP_TRUNC(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(v.IPv6Address), 64))
from (
  select struct(
     "254.34.78.20" as `IPV4Address`,
     "2a02:c7e:3f0d:e00:48e:abff:d697:9cc2" as `IPv6Address`
  ) as v
)
```

It returns:

| v | f0_ | f1_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| { "IPV4Address": "254.34.78.20", "IPv6Address": "2a02:c7e:3f0d:e00:48e:abff:d697:9cc2" } | 254.34.78.0 | 2a02:c7e:3f0d:e00:: |

I'd simply like to know why these functions return a 0 for the truncated portion of the IPv4 address but nothing for the truncated portion of the IPv6 address.

I know this isn't really a BigQuery question per se as its more about networks and I suspect BigQuery is just doing what any other such library would do... but interested to know why this is nonetheless. Maybe I'll tag it with `IPv6` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd simply like to know why these functions return a 0 for the
> truncated portion of the IPv4 address but nothing for the truncated
> portion of the IPv6 address.

It *is* returning `0` for the truncated part of the IPv6 address.

IPv6 addresses can have several forms, but the canonical form requires you to shorten the longest run of `0` fields with a double colon (`::`). That is at the end of your address `2a02:c7e:3f0d:e00::`, and that means it is `2a02:c7e:3f0d:e00:0:0:0:0` properly shortened.